# Orika mapper NPE between 2 maps

Tags: java, javabeans, orika

I have 2 objects that have the same "links" property, and when using Orika to map from `A` -> `B`, I get

```
  ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException:ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: 
While attempting the following mapping:
    sourceType = A
    sourceProperty = links(Links)
    destinationType = B
    destinationProperty = links(Links)
    Error occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.addMapMethod(MapperGenerator.java:170)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:70)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.VariableRef.isPrimitive(VariableRef.java:167)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.VariableRef.<init>(VariableRef.java:95)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.specification.MapToMap.generateMappingCode(MapToMap.java:71)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.SourceCodeContext.mapFields(SourceCodeContext.java:778)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.generateFieldMapCode(MapperGenerator.java:247)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.addMapMethod(MapperGenerator.java:167)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

The objects are defined like so:

```
class A {
  private Links links
  // getter/setter + other fields
}

class B { 
  private Links links
  // getter/setter + other fields
}

class Links extends HashMap<String, List<Link>> {
}

class Link {
  private String text;
}
```

I'm using the default mapper like so:

```
mapper.classMap(A.class, B.class)
      .byDefault()
      .register();
```

Any suggestions for proceeding?

Comment: Run it in a debugger with a breakpoint on the NullPointerException constructor so you can see the stack trace

Comment: Right, it says that links(Links) is the property that's causing the NPE

Comment: In the future, always post the stack trace

Comment: @SeanF thanks - looks like the stack trace did reveal more info that I hadn't noticed earlier

Comment: yw, you can also thank me by hitting the up arrow or selecting as answer

Answer (score 1):

YOu're seeing this:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/orika/issues/170

It says the issue was fixed here but it doesn't look the same to me: https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/issues/67

or maybe this one is what you're seeing:
https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/issues/232

Your issue looks identical to the one posted at code.google.com

Comment: I just added the full stack trace, and I do see a "at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.VariableRef.isPrimitive(VariableRef.java:167)" being mentioned, so it does look like the same issue.. maybe a new variation of it. I'm using 1.5.2

Comment: not so sure it was ever fixed, the github issue claiming to fix it looks like a different issue to me